# How to use pandas to read csv files in python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

When I try to read a csv fie using the code pandas.read_csv("data.csv") the result is not shown in a table with borders only like this;

```
               Class  CTLA4   PD1  PD1CTLA4  CD57  CD57+CD28-  PD1CD57  
44  ASYMPTOMATIC_CD4   0.67  1.57     0.160  0.00        0.00    0.000   
45  ASYMPTOMATIC_CD4   0.50  0.64     0.110  2.46        2.39    0.036   
46  ASYMPTOMATIC_CD4   0.67  0.45     0.220  1.56        1.29    0.130
```

What code do I need to write to make Spyder show the csv file as a proper table with border lines?

Comment: What is your separator? whitespace?

Comment: @Ama Owusu-Darko -  Do you need table format border in your print statment?

Comment: @MohamedThasinah Yes, how do I get the table format border instead of the whitespace as a separator?

Comment: @Ama Owusu-Darko - use tabulate package. For example to get border use this, print tabulate(df, df.columns,tablefmt='grid'). For more details visit https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/

Comment: Thank you. (Sorry for late reply)